# how can i access to data from another bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

hey guys i'm new with bloc pattern and i have some questions

1. How I can get props data from a State inside BlocBuilder for another bloc ?
2. already worked with provider (state management) and it's easy to access to any data from everywhere , is that possible with bloc and how ?
   thank you

Comment: this is very simple please document carefully, you get to know https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks guy i think i find the solution of this question 
ist's data shouldn't be in the bloc, data should be in a repository. Then, you can use RepositoryProvider or MultiRepositoryProvider  in order to get any data from any bloc in the subtree.

Answer (score 1):

To access other blocs props you have to hold its instance, and from it, you can acquire its state. I have addressed this in the [blog post](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/flutter-bloc) that I have written.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that I understood your question correctly,
You have a piece of data stored in state in bloc A and you want to use that data in bloc B.

For instance a post Bloc which needs to fetch all the posts by a logged in user (assuming that the logged in user has been stored in state in the user Bloc).

Defining the event:

```
class FetchPost extends PostEvent{
 final User currentUser
}
```

when dispatching the FetchPost event:

Note: if you are dispatching the event from your view, you have to get the bloc from `Provider.of(context)`

```
PostBloc _postBloc = Provider.of<TransactionBloc>(context);
UserBloc _userBloc = Provider.of<UserBloc>(context);
_postBloc.dispatch(FetchPost(_userBloc.currentState.loggedInUser))
```